# react-native set first page depending on authorize

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

How can I display the login page if the user is not authorized or a list of items?

I'm using react-native-router-flux

```
<Router>
    <Scene key="user">
        <Scene key="register1" component={RegisterStep1} title="register1"/>
        <Scene key="register2" component={RegisterStep2} title="register2"/>
        <Scene key="register3" component={RegisterStep3} title="register3"/>
        <Scene key="login" component={Login} title="Login"/>
    </Scene>
    <Scene key="items" type={ActionConst.REPLACE}>
        <Scene key="list" component={ItemList} title="Items list"/>
        <Scene key="detail" component={ItemDetail} title="Item detail"/>
    </Scene>
</Router>
```

is it right?

I should go to login Scene or items -> list Scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the user is authorized in the `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` lifecycle methods of your main component(The one that has the Router component) and call `Actions.items()` after everything goes well. Otherwise go to the login screen.

Also I recommend two things:

-Put your scenes inside a `root` scene as recommended by `react-native-router-flux`

-Set one of your screens as initial (with the prop of the scene: `initial={true}` so that the user can see something before your lifecycle method does its work.

Comment: Thank you. 
I did this using an `state logged`. In the `componentWillMount` checks and if logged in sets the state of the `logged=true`. In the `Scene` there is the value `initial = {this.state.logged}` for key `user` and `initial={!this.state.logged}` for key `items`